# Pure ASP upload with image detection

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

How to upload files from browser to server running classic ASP and detect, server side, if the files are valid pictures? For valid pictures, how to get their dimensions?

Usually file upload in classic ASP is done by third party components which come with a DLL file and requires registration on the server, sometimes also cost money. Needless to say many hosts won't allow third party components due to security reasons.

There are great many pure ASP upload scripts already, but they only take the file and save to server disk, no image detection whatsoever.

Below is my own script written for the above purpose but of course more answers are always welcome with alternatives or better ways.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a single Class which handles file upload plus image detection. Use case will come below. Save this as-is, preferably as a new file, with `.asp` extension e.g. *ShadowUpload.asp*

**Note**: if you want to allow uploading images larger than 200kb, take a look in the answer to [Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes) throws error for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209227/request-binaryreadrequest-totalbytes-throws-error-for-large-files). (Failing to do so might result in "Operation not Allowed" error on the BinaryRead line.)

```vbs
<%
'constants:
Const MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE=1500000 'bytes
Const MSG_NO_DATA="nothing to upload!"
Const MSG_EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE="you exceeded the maximum upload size!"
Const SU_DEBUG_MODE=False

Class ShadowUpload
    Private m_Request
    Private m_Files
    Private m_Error

    Public Property Get GetError
        GetError = m_Error
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileCount
        FileCount = m_Files.Count
    End Property

    Public Function File(index)
        Dim keys
        keys = m_Files.Keys
        Set File = m_Files(keys(index))
    End Function

    Public Default Property Get Item(strName)
        If m_Request.Exists(strName) Then
            Item = m_Request(strName)
        Else  
            Item = ""
        End If
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Dim iBytesCount, strBinData

        'first of all, get amount of uploaded bytes:
        iBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes

        WriteDebug("initializing upload, bytes: " & iBytesCount & "<br />")

        'abort if nothing there:
        If iBytesCount=0 Then
            m_Error = MSG_NO_DATA
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'abort if exceeded maximum upload size:
        If iBytesCount>MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE Then
            m_Error = MSG_EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'read the binary data:
        strBinData = Request.BinaryRead(iBytesCount)

        'create private collections:
        Set m_Request = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set m_Files = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        'populate the collection:
        Call BuildUpload(strBinData)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        Dim fileName
        If IsObject(m_Request) Then
            m_Request.RemoveAll
            Set m_Request = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(m_Files) Then
            For Each fileName In m_Files.Keys
                Set m_Files(fileName)=Nothing
            Next
            m_Files.RemoveAll
            Set m_Files = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BuildUpload(ByVal strBinData)
        Dim strBinQuote, strBinCRLF, iValuePos
        Dim iPosBegin, iPosEnd, strBoundaryData
        Dim strBoundaryEnd, iCurPosition, iBoundaryEndPos
        Dim strElementName, strFileName, objFileData
        Dim strFileType, strFileData, strElementValue

        strBinQuote = AsciiToBinary(chr(34))
        strBinCRLF = AsciiToBinary(chr(13))

        'find the boundaries
        iPosBegin = 1
        iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBinCRLF)
        strBoundaryData = MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin)
        iCurPosition = InstrB(1, strBinData, strBoundaryData)
        strBoundaryEnd = strBoundaryData & AsciiToBinary("--")
        iBoundaryEndPos = InstrB(strBinData, strBoundaryEnd)

        'read binary data into private collection:
        Do until (iCurPosition>=iBoundaryEndPos) Or (iCurPosition=0)
            'skip non relevant data...
            iPosBegin = InstrB(iCurPosition, strBinData, AsciiToBinary("Content-Disposition"))
            iPosBegin = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, AsciiToBinary("name="))
            iValuePos = iPosBegin

            'read the name of the form element, e.g. "file1", "text1"
            iPosBegin = iPosBegin+6
            iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBinQuote)
            strElementName = BinaryToAscii(MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin))

            'maybe file?
            iPosBegin = InstrB(iCurPosition, strBinData, AsciiToBinary("filename="))
            iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosEnd, strBinData, strBoundaryData)
            If (iPosBegin>0) And (iPosBegin<iPosEnd) Then
                'skip non relevant data..
                iPosBegin = iPosBegin+10

                'read file name:
                iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBinQuote)
                strFileName = BinaryToAscii(MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin))

                'verify that we got name:
                If Len(strFileName)>0 Then
                    'create file data:
                    Set objFileData = New FileData
                    objFileData.FileName = strFileName

                    'read file type:
                    iPosBegin = InstrB(iPosEnd, strBinData, AsciiToBinary("Content-Type:"))
                    iPosBegin = iPosBegin+14
                    iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBinCRLF)
                    strFileType = BinaryToAscii(MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin))
                    objFileData.ContentType = strFileType

                    'read file contents:
                    iPosBegin = iPosEnd+4
                    iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBoundaryData)-2
                    strFileData = MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin)

                    'check that not empty:
                    If LenB(strFileData)>0 Then
                        objFileData.Contents = strFileData

                        'append to files collection if not empty:
                        Set m_Files(strFileName) = objFileData
                    Else  
                        Set objFileData = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                strElementValue = strFileName
            Else  
                'ordinary form value, just read:
                iPosBegin = InstrB(iValuePos, strBinData, strBinCRLF)
                iPosBegin = iPosBegin+4
                iPosEnd = InstrB(iPosBegin, strBinData, strBoundaryData)-2
                strElementValue = BinaryToAscii(MidB(strBinData, iPosBegin, iPosEnd-iPosBegin))
            End If

            'append to request collection
            m_Request(strElementName) = strElementValue

            'skip to next element:
            iCurPosition = InstrB(iCurPosition+LenB(strBoundaryData), strBinData, strBoundaryData)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Function WriteDebug(msg)
        If SU_DEBUG_MODE Then
            Response.Write(msg)
            Response.Flush
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function AsciiToBinary(strAscii)
        Dim i, char, result
        result = ""
        For i=1 to Len(strAscii)
            char = Mid(strAscii, i, 1)
            result = result & chrB(AscB(char))
        Next
        AsciiToBinary = result
    End Function

    Private Function BinaryToAscii(strBinary)
        Dim i, result
        result = ""
        For i=1 to LenB(strBinary)
            result = result & chr(AscB(MidB(strBinary, i, 1))) 
        Next
        BinaryToAscii = result
    End Function
End Class

Class FileData
    Private m_fileName
    Private m_contentType
    Private m_BinaryContents
    Private m_AsciiContents
    Private m_imageWidth
    Private m_imageHeight
    Private m_checkImage

    Public Property Get FileName
        FileName = m_fileName
    End Property

    Public Property Get ContentType
        ContentType = m_contentType
    End Property

    Public Property Get ImageWidth
        If m_checkImage=False Then Call CheckImageDimensions
        ImageWidth = m_imageWidth
    End Property

    Public Property Get ImageHeight
        If m_checkImage=False Then Call CheckImageDimensions
        ImageHeight = m_imageHeight
    End Property

    Public Property Let FileName(strName)
        Dim arrTemp
        arrTemp = Split(strName, "\")
        m_fileName = arrTemp(UBound(arrTemp))
    End Property

    Public Property Let CheckImage(blnCheck)
        m_checkImage = blnCheck
    End Property

    Public Property Let ContentType(strType)
        m_contentType = strType
    End Property

    Public Property Let Contents(strData)
        m_BinaryContents = strData
        m_AsciiContents = RSBinaryToString(m_BinaryContents)
    End Property

    Public Property Get Size
        Size = LenB(m_BinaryContents)
    End Property

    Private Sub CheckImageDimensions
        Dim width, height, colors
        Dim strType

        '''If gfxSpex(BinaryToAscii(m_BinaryContents), width, height, colors, strType) = true then
        If gfxSpex(m_AsciiContents, width, height, colors, strType) = true then
            m_imageWidth = width
            m_imageHeight = height
        End If
        m_checkImage = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        m_imageWidth = -1
        m_imageHeight = -1
        m_checkImage = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveToDisk(strFolderPath, ByRef strNewFileName)
        Dim strPath, objFSO, objFile
        Dim i, time1, time2
        Dim objStream, strExtension

        strPath = strFolderPath&"\"
        If Len(strNewFileName)=0 Then
            strPath = strPath & m_fileName
        Else  
            strExtension = GetExtension(strNewFileName)
            If Len(strExtension)=0 Then
                strNewFileName = strNewFileName & "." & GetExtension(m_fileName)
            End If
            strPath = strPath & strNewFileName
        End If

        WriteDebug("save file started...<br />")

        time1 = CDbl(Timer)

        Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strPath)

        objFile.Write(m_AsciiContents)

        '''For i=1 to LenB(m_BinaryContents)
        '''    objFile.Write chr(AscB(MidB(m_BinaryContents, i, 1)))
        '''Next          

        time2 = CDbl(Timer)
        WriteDebug("saving file took " & (time2-time1) & " seconds.<br />")

        objFile.Close
        Set objFile=Nothing
        Set objFSO=Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Function GetExtension(strPath)
        Dim arrTemp
        arrTemp = Split(strPath, ".")
        GetExtension = ""
        If UBound(arrTemp)>0 Then
            GetExtension = arrTemp(UBound(arrTemp))
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
        'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
        'RSBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
        'to a string (BSTR) using ADO recordset

        Dim Binary
        'MultiByte data must be converted To VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY first.
        If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

        Dim RS, LBinary
        Const adLongVarChar = 201
        Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        LBinary = LenB(Binary)

        If LBinary>0 Then
            RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
            RS.Open
            RS.AddNew
            RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary 
            RS.Update
            RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
        Else  
            RSBinaryToString = ""
        End If
    End Function

    Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
        '© 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
        ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
        ' Using recordset
        Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
        Const adLongVarBinary = 205
        Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
        If LMultiByte>0 Then
            RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
            RS.Open
            RS.AddNew
            RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
            RS.Update
            Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
        End If
        MultiByteToBinary = Binary
    End Function

    Private Function WriteDebug(msg)
        If SU_DEBUG_MODE Then
            Response.Write(msg)
            Response.Flush
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function BinaryToAscii(strBinary)
        Dim i, result
        result = ""
        For i=1 to LenB(strBinary)
            result = result & chr(AscB(MidB(strBinary, i, 1))) 
        Next
        BinaryToAscii = result
    End Function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This routine will attempt to identify any filespec passed  :::
    ':::  as a graphic file (regardless of the extension). This will :::
    ':::  work with BMP, GIF, JPG and PNG files.                     :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::          Based on ideas presented by David Crowell          :::
    ':::                   (credit where due)                        :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah     Copyright *c* MM,  Mike Shaffer     blah blah :::
    '::: bh blah      ALL RIGHTS RESERVED WORLDWIDE      blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah  Permission is granted to use this code blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah   in your projects, as long as this     blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah      copyright notice is included       blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This function gets a specified number of bytes from any    :::
    ':::  file, starting at the offset (base 1)                      :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Passed:                                                    :::
    ':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::
    ':::       offset      => Offset at which to start reading       :::
    ':::       bytes       => How many bytes to read                 :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Private Function GetBytes(flnm, offset, bytes)
        Dim startPos
        If offset=0 Then
            startPos = 1
        Else  
            startPos = offset
        End If
        if bytes = -1 then        ' Get All!
            GetBytes = flnm
        else
            GetBytes = Mid(flnm, startPos, bytes)
        end if
'        Dim objFSO
'        Dim objFTemp
'        Dim objTextStream
'        Dim lngSize
'        
'        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'        
'        ' First, we get the filesize
'        Set objFTemp = objFSO.GetFile(flnm)
'        lngSize = objFTemp.Size
'        set objFTemp = nothing
'        
'        fsoForReading = 1
'        Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(flnm, fsoForReading)
'        
'        if offset > 0 then
'            strBuff = objTextStream.Read(offset - 1)
'        end if
'        
'        if bytes = -1 then        ' Get All!
'            GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(lngSize)  'ReadAll
'        else
'            GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(bytes)
'        end if
'        
'        objTextStream.Close
'        set objTextStream = nothing
'        set objFSO = nothing
    End Function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Functions to convert two bytes to a numeric value (long)   :::
    ':::  (both little-endian and big-endian)                        :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Private Function lngConvert(strTemp)
        lngConvert = clng(asc(left(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(right(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
    end function

    Private Function lngConvert2(strTemp)
        lngConvert2 = clng(asc(right(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(left(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
    end function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This function does most of the real work. It will attempt  :::
    ':::  to read any file, regardless of the extension, and will    :::
    ':::  identify if it is a graphical image.                       :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Passed:                                                    :::
    ':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::
    ':::       width       => width of image                         :::
    ':::       height      => height of image                        :::
    ':::       depth       => color depth (in number of colors)      :::
    ':::       strImageType=> type of image (e.g. GIF, BMP, etc.)    :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    function gfxSpex(flnm, width, height, depth, strImageType)
        dim strPNG 
        dim strGIF
        dim strBMP
        dim strType
        dim strBuff
        dim lngSize
        dim flgFound
        dim strTarget
        dim lngPos
        dim ExitLoop
        dim lngMarkerSize

        strType = ""
        strImageType = "(unknown)"

        gfxSpex = False

        strPNG = chr(137) & chr(80) & chr(78)
        strGIF = "GIF"
        strBMP = chr(66) & chr(77)

        strType = GetBytes(flnm, 0, 3)

        if strType = strGIF then                ' is GIF
            strImageType = "GIF"
            Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 7, 2))
            Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 9, 2))
            Depth = 2 ^ ((asc(GetBytes(flnm, 11, 1)) and 7) + 1)
            gfxSpex = True
        elseif left(strType, 2) = strBMP then        ' is BMP
            strImageType = "BMP"
            Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
            Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
            Depth = 2 ^ (asc(GetBytes(flnm, 29, 1)))
            gfxSpex = True
        elseif strType = strPNG then            ' Is PNG
            strImageType = "PNG"
            Width = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
            Height = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
            Depth = getBytes(flnm, 25, 2)
            select case asc(right(Depth,1))
                case 0
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 2
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 3)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 3
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))  '8
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 4
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 2)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 6
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 4)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case else
                    Depth = -1
            end select
        else
            strBuff = GetBytes(flnm, 0, -1)        ' Get all bytes from file
            lngSize = len(strBuff)
            flgFound = 0

            strTarget = chr(255) & chr(216) & chr(255)
            flgFound = instr(strBuff, strTarget)

            if flgFound = 0 then
                exit function
            end if

            strImageType = "JPG"
            lngPos = flgFound + 2
            ExitLoop = false

            do while ExitLoop = False and lngPos < lngSize
                do while asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) = 255 and lngPos < lngSize
                    lngPos = lngPos + 1
                loop

                if asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) < 192 or asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) > 195 then
                    lngMarkerSize = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 1, 2))
                    lngPos = lngPos + lngMarkerSize  + 1
                else
                    ExitLoop = True
                end if
            loop

            if ExitLoop = False then
                Width = -1
                Height = -1
                Depth = -1
            else
                Height = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 4, 2))
                Width = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 6, 2))
                Depth = 2 ^ (asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 8, 1)) * 8)
                gfxSpex = True
            end if
        end if
    End Function
End Class
%>
```

Constants explained:

- *MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE* - maximum size, in bytes, of all uploaded files. When exceeding that size the upload process is aborted and global error is set to the constant *MSG_EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE*.
- *MSG_NO_DATA* - when user does not choose any file to upload, global error will be set to that constant.
- *SU_DEBUG_MODE* - when set to `True` the script will output various messages via `Response.Write()`, useful for debugging problems.

Simple use case: (full code)

```vbs
<!-- #include file="ShadowUpload.asp" -->
<%
Dim objUpload
If Request("action")="1" Then
    Set objUpload=New ShadowUpload
    If objUpload.GetError<>"" Then
        Response.Write("sorry, could not upload: "&objUpload.GetError)
    Else  
        Response.Write("found "&objUpload.FileCount&" files...<br />")
        For x=0 To objUpload.FileCount-1
            Response.Write("file name: "&objUpload.File(x).FileName&"<br />")
            Response.Write("file type: "&objUpload.File(x).ContentType&"<br />")
            Response.Write("file size: "&objUpload.File(x).Size&"<br />")
            Response.Write("image width: "&objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth&"<br />")
            Response.Write("image height: "&objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight&"<br />")
            If (objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth>200) Or (objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight>200) Then
                Response.Write("image to big, not saving!")
            Else  
                Call objUpload.File(x).SaveToDisk(Server.MapPath("Uploads"), "")
                Response.Write("file saved successfully!")
            End If
            Response.Write("<hr />")
        Next
        Response.Write("thank you, "&objUpload("name"))
    End If
End If
%>
<form action="<%=Request.ServerVariables( "Script_Name" )%>?action=1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
File1: <input type="file" name="file1" /><br />
File2: <input type="file" name="file2" /><br />
File3: <input type="file" name="file3" /><br />
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

This demonstrates using most of the script features, to block non image files from uploading you can just have something like:

```vbs
If objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth<0 Then
    Response.Write("Not a valid image!")
Else  
    'proceed to save the file...
End If
```

Disclaimer: This was originally posted [here](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-additional-features-94647.html) seven years ago and as credited in the code itself, contains parts not written by me.

**Note for clients using Chrome browser on android device**:

1. For some reason, the standard `<button>` element of type submit appears not to work properly in Chrome for android. If you get complaints from clients about it, try changing this line in the form:

   ```
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   ```

   to this instead:

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
   ```
2. Due to possible bug in the Chrome app for android, when using the phone's camera app to take a new image then trying to submit this image, it might fail. In such case just advice the client to use a different browser.

Comment: Very good. Also, I changed the file name in the "include" statement to match what you recommended for a name at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Shadow Wizard!  Worked like a charm.  I'm trying to take out the image part which is not relevant for me.  Great code set to start from!

Comment: Cheers @Dave let me know if you bump into any obstacle. :)

Comment: Not an obstacle, but in re-using its code is some of that multi-byte to single byte stuff necessary if all you want to do is accept the file and don't care if it's an image, has dimensions, is a particular format, and so forth?  I deactivated some of that excess, but looking to discern how to pare this GREAT code down to the bare minimum.

Comment: @Dave fair request, I will update my post here soon with a "minified" version of the code that can used for ordinary files. Ping me if I forget, in two days or so. :)

Comment: Good stuff, but it doesn't quite handle my scenario, I'm passing over other form fields with my file type inputs.  Setting the enctype to multi-part empties the request object.  Thereby I would need something like the .Form method from http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm but that one doesn't do images. An example being objUpload.Form("myfield").  I think it would make the class a lot better, but am unsure of how to mod it myself.

Comment: @RandomUs1r the code already supports it, see in the sample code `Response.Write("thank you, "&objUpload("name"))`. This would show what the user wrote in input element like `<input type="text" name="name" />`.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Oh, completely missed that in the sample, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Another question, how would I call SaveToDisk for a specific file, like... Call objUpload.File("test").SaveToDisk(Server.MapPath("Uploads"), "") if it's possible that is.

Comment: Should be simple enough to alter the code, will take a look tomorrow. :)

Comment: Actually I took another approach by comparing the filename of x to the filename fields I'm expecting to figure out which file's which for different dimensions.  It would still make the class more flexible though to do so if you still want.

Comment: im getting weird file names when using hebrew in the form input. trying to give the file the name of the user and its in hebrew. i added <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%> but this doesnt solve this

Comment: @NoamSmadja I'm afraid it's browser related, unless there are sites where you download files with Hebrew names and there it's fine?

Comment: to debug, I chose a name in hebrew directly, instead of pulling the name from objUpload("variable") and it works. so my guess is that it is something to do with how you parse the form variables. i tried looking for encoding there but it's above my knowledge.

Comment: @NoamSmadja interesting, I'll try to revive my local environment for classic ASP to try and reproduce then I might be able to find a fix. Can't know when I'll have the time though.

Comment: its not urgent, i overcome that by setting a cookie with the hebrew text instead of passing it as a form date

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar found time to look into it? the browser is not the issue, i run hebrew on it easily. also, when passing variables in a post or get it works well. only when using shadowupload im no succeeding getting the encoding correctly

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar i added Response.CodePage = 1252 into shadowupload.asp and now in the browser console, the hebrew shows correctly, but, in the browser my encoding is 65001 (utf-8) so all the rest is wrong. i hope this gives you some ideas of how to debug this

Comment: @NoamSmadja not yet, sadly. :/

Answer (score 1):

The code of @ShadowWizard is nice and run as a charme on a local machine, but I encountered uploading issues on a production server, then I rewrote the Class with a more robust parsing routine for the upload request.

The class can handle more errors right now and You can upload multiple files with a single INPUT element; save this as a new file and rename it as "uploadhelper.asp"

```
<%
Const MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE        = 25000000 '25 MB
Const MSG_NO_DATA            = "Nothing to upload."
Const MSG_EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE  = "You exceeded the maximum upload size."
Const MSG_BAD_REQUEST_METHOD = "Bad request method. Use the POST method."
Const MSG_BAD_ENCTYPE        = "Bad encoding type. Use a ""multipart/form-data"" enctype."
Const MSG_ZERO_LENGTH        = "Zero length request."

Class UploadHelper
    Private m_Request
    Private m_Files
    Private m_Error

    Public Property Get GetError
        GetError = m_Error
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileCount
        FileCount = m_Files.Count
    End Property

    Public Function File(index)
        If m_Files.Exists(index) Then
           Set File = m_Files(index)
        Else  
           Set File = Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    Public Default Property Get Item(strName)
        If m_Request.Exists(strName) Then
            Item = m_Request(strName)
        Else  
            Item = ""
        End If
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Dim iBytesCount, strBinData

        'first of all, get amount of uploaded bytes:
        iBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes

        'abort if nothing there:
        If iBytesCount = 0 Then
            m_Error = MSG_NO_DATA
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'abort if exceeded maximum upload size:
        If iBytesCount > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE Then
            m_Error = MSG_EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then 
            Dim CT, PosB, Boundary, PosE
            CT = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_Content_Type")
            If LCase(Left(CT, 19)) = "multipart/form-data" Then
                PosB = InStr(LCase(CT), "boundary=") 
                If PosB > 0 Then Boundary = Mid(CT, PosB + 9) 
                PosB = InStr(LCase(CT), "boundary=") 
                If PosB > 0 Then 
                    PosB = InStr(Boundary, ",")
                    If PosB > 0 Then Boundary = Left(Boundary, PosB - 1)
                End If
                If iBytesCount > 0 And Boundary <> "" Then 
                    Boundary = "--" & Boundary
                    Dim Head, Binary
                    Binary = Request.BinaryRead(iBytesCount) 

                    'create private collections:
                    Set m_Request = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    Set m_Files = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

                    Call ParseRequest(Binary, Boundary)
                    Binary = Empty 
                Else
                    m_Error = MSG_ZERO_LENGTH
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                m_Error = MSG_BAD_ENCTYPE
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            m_Error = MSG_BAD_REQUEST_METHOD
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Terminate
        Dim fileName
        If IsObject(m_Request) Then
            m_Request.RemoveAll
            Set m_Request = Nothing
        End If
        If IsObject(m_Files) Then
            For Each fileName In m_Files.Keys
                Set m_Files(fileName)=Nothing
            Next
            m_Files.RemoveAll
            Set m_Files = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ParseRequest(Binary, Boundary)
        Dim PosOpenBoundary, PosCloseBoundary, PosEndOfHeader, isLastBoundary
        Boundary = StringToBinary(Boundary)
        PosOpenBoundary = InStrB(Binary, Boundary)
        PosCloseBoundary = InStrB(PosOpenBoundary + LenB(Boundary), Binary, Boundary, 0)
        Dim HeaderContent, FieldContent, bFieldContent
        Dim Content_Disposition, FormFieldName, SourceFileName, Content_Type
        Dim TwoCharsAfterEndBoundary, n : n = 0
        Do While (PosOpenBoundary > 0 And PosCloseBoundary > 0 And Not isLastBoundary)
            PosEndOfHeader = InStrB(PosOpenBoundary + Len(Boundary), Binary, StringToBinary(vbCrLf + vbCrLf))
            HeaderContent = MidB(Binary, PosOpenBoundary + LenB(Boundary) + 2, PosEndOfHeader - PosOpenBoundary - LenB(Boundary) - 2)
            bFieldContent = MidB(Binary, (PosEndOfHeader + 4), PosCloseBoundary - (PosEndOfHeader + 4) - 2)
            GetHeadFields BinaryToString(HeaderContent), Content_Disposition, FormFieldName, SourceFileName, Content_Type
            Set objFileData = New FileData
            objFileData.FileName = SourceFileName
            objFileData.ContentType = Content_Type
            objFileData.Contents = bFieldContent
            objFileData.FormFieldName = FormFieldName
            objFileData.ContentDisposition = Content_Disposition
            Set m_Files(n) = objFileData
            Set objFileData = Nothing
            TwoCharsAfterEndBoundary = BinaryToString(MidB(Binary, PosCloseBoundary + LenB(Boundary), 2))
            isLastBoundary = TwoCharsAfterEndBoundary = "--"
            If Not isLastBoundary Then 
                PosOpenBoundary = PosCloseBoundary
                PosCloseBoundary = InStrB(PosOpenBoundary + LenB(Boundary), Binary, Boundary)
            End If
            n = n + 1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Function GetHeadFields(ByVal Head, Content_Disposition, Name, FileName, Content_Type)
        Content_Disposition = LTrim(SeparateField(Head, "content-disposition:", ";"))
        Name = (SeparateField(Head, "name=", ";")) 
        If Left(Name, 1) = """" Then Name = Mid(Name, 2, Len(Name) - 2)
        FileName = (SeparateField(Head, "filename=", ";")) 
        If Left(FileName, 1) = """" Then FileName = Mid(FileName, 2, Len(FileName) - 2)
        Content_Type = LTrim(SeparateField(Head, "content-type:", ";"))
    End Function

    Private Function SeparateField(From, ByVal sStart, ByVal sEnd)
        Dim PosB, PosE, sFrom
        sFrom = LCase(From)
        PosB = InStr(sFrom, sStart)
        If PosB > 0 Then
            PosB = PosB + Len(sStart)
            PosE = InStr(PosB, sFrom, sEnd)
            If PosE = 0 Then PosE = InStr(PosB, sFrom, vbCrLf)
            If PosE = 0 Then PosE = Len(sFrom) + 1
            SeparateField = Mid(From, PosB, PosE - PosB)
        Else
            SeparateField = Empty
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function BinaryToString(Binary)
        dim cl1, cl2, cl3, pl1, pl2, pl3
        Dim L
        cl1 = 1
        cl2 = 1
        cl3 = 1
        L = LenB(Binary)
        Do While cl1<=L
            pl3 = pl3 & Chr(AscB(MidB(Binary,cl1,1)))
            cl1 = cl1 + 1
            cl3 = cl3 + 1
            if cl3>300 then
                pl2 = pl2 & pl3
                pl3 = ""
                cl3 = 1
                cl2 = cl2 + 1
                if cl2>200 then
                    pl1 = pl1 & pl2
                    pl2 = ""
                    cl2 = 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        BinaryToString = pl1 & pl2 & pl3
    End Function

    Private Function StringToBinary(String)
        Dim I, B
        For I=1 to len(String)
            B = B & ChrB(Asc(Mid(String,I,1)))
        Next
        StringToBinary = B
    End Function

End Class

Class FileData
    Private m_fileName
    Private m_contentType
    Private m_BinaryContents
    Private m_AsciiContents
    Private m_imageWidth
    Private m_imageHeight
    Private m_checkImage
    Private m_formFieldName
    Private m_contentDisposition

    Public Property Get FormFieldName
        FormFieldName = m_formFieldName
    End Property

    Public Property Let FormFieldName(sFieldName)
        m_formFieldName = sFieldName
    End Property

    Public Property Get ContentDisposition
        ContentDisposition = m_contentDisposition
    End Property

    Public Property Let ContentDisposition(sContentDisposition)
        m_contentDisposition = sContentDisposition
    End Property

    Public Property Get FileName
        FileName = m_fileName
    End Property

    Public Property Get ContentType
        ContentType = m_contentType
    End Property

    Public Property Get ImageWidth
        If m_checkImage=False Then Call CheckImageDimensions
        ImageWidth = m_imageWidth
    End Property

    Public Property Get ImageHeight
        If m_checkImage=False Then Call CheckImageDimensions
        ImageHeight = m_imageHeight
    End Property

    Public Property Let FileName(ByVal strName)
        strName = Replace(strName, "/", "\")
        Dim arrTemp : arrTemp = Split(strName, "\")
        m_fileName = arrTemp(UBound(arrTemp))
    End Property

    Public Property Let CheckImage(blnCheck)
        m_checkImage = blnCheck
    End Property

    Public Property Let ContentType(strType)
        m_contentType = strType
    End Property

    Public Property Let Contents(strData)
        m_BinaryContents = strData
        m_AsciiContents = RSBinaryToString(m_BinaryContents)
    End Property

    Public Property Get Size
        Size = LenB(m_BinaryContents)
    End Property

    Private Sub CheckImageDimensions
        Dim width, height, colors
        Dim strType

        '''If gfxSpex(BinaryToAscii(m_BinaryContents), width, height, colors, strType) = true then
        If gfxSpex(m_AsciiContents, width, height, colors, strType) = true then
            m_imageWidth = width
            m_imageHeight = height
        End If
        m_checkImage = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        m_imageWidth = -1
        m_imageHeight = -1
        m_checkImage = False
    End Sub

    Public Sub SaveToDisk(strFolderPath, ByRef strNewFileName)
        Dim strPath, objFSO, objFile
        Dim i, time1, time2
        Dim objStream, strExtension

        strPath = strFolderPath&"\"
        If Len(strNewFileName)=0 Then
            strPath = strPath & m_fileName
        Else  
            strExtension = GetExtension(strNewFileName)
            If Len(strExtension)=0 Then
                strNewFileName = strNewFileName & "." & GetExtension(m_fileName)
            End If
            strPath = strPath & strNewFileName
        End If

        time1 = CDbl(Timer)

        Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strPath)

        objFile.Write(m_AsciiContents)

        '''For i=1 to LenB(m_BinaryContents)
        '''    objFile.Write chr(AscB(MidB(m_BinaryContents, i, 1)))
        '''Next          

        time2 = CDbl(Timer)

        objFile.Close
        Set objFile=Nothing
        Set objFSO=Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Function GetExtension(strPath)
        Dim arrTemp
        arrTemp = Split(strPath, ".")
        GetExtension = ""
        If UBound(arrTemp)>0 Then
            GetExtension = arrTemp(UBound(arrTemp))
        End If
    End Function

    Private Function RSBinaryToString(xBinary)
        'Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
        'RSBinaryToString converts binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY Or MultiByte string)
        'to a string (BSTR) using ADO recordset

        Dim Binary
        'MultiByte data must be converted To VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY first.
        If vartype(xBinary)=8 Then Binary = MultiByteToBinary(xBinary) Else Binary = xBinary

        Dim RS, LBinary
        Const adLongVarChar = 201
        Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        LBinary = LenB(Binary)

        If LBinary>0 Then
            RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarChar, LBinary
            RS.Open
            RS.AddNew
            RS("mBinary").AppendChunk Binary 
            RS.Update
            RSBinaryToString = RS("mBinary")
        Else  
            RSBinaryToString = ""
        End If
    End Function

    Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
        '© 2000 Antonin Foller, http://www.motobit.com
        ' MultiByteToBinary converts multibyte string To real binary data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
        ' Using recordset
        Dim RS, LMultiByte, Binary
        Const adLongVarBinary = 205
        Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
        If LMultiByte>0 Then
            RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
            RS.Open
            RS.AddNew
            RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
            RS.Update
            Binary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
        End If
        MultiByteToBinary = Binary
    End Function

    Private Function BinaryToAscii(strBinary)
        Dim i, result
        result = ""
        For i=1 to LenB(strBinary)
            result = result & chr(AscB(MidB(strBinary, i, 1))) 
        Next
        BinaryToAscii = result
    End Function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This routine will attempt to identify any filespec passed  :::
    ':::  as a graphic file (regardless of the extension). This will :::
    ':::  work with BMP, GIF, JPG and PNG files.                     :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::          Based on ideas presented by David Crowell          :::
    ':::                   (credit where due)                        :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah     Copyright *c* MM,  Mike Shaffer     blah blah :::
    '::: bh blah      ALL RIGHTS RESERVED WORLDWIDE      blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah  Permission is granted to use this code blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah   in your projects, as long as this     blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah      copyright notice is included       blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    '::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This function gets a specified number of bytes from any    :::
    ':::  file, starting at the offset (base 1)                      :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Passed:                                                    :::
    ':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::
    ':::       offset      => Offset at which to start reading       :::
    ':::       bytes       => How many bytes to read                 :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Private Function GetBytes(flnm, offset, bytes)
        Dim startPos
        If offset=0 Then
            startPos = 1
        Else  
            startPos = offset
        End If
        if bytes = -1 then        ' Get All!
            GetBytes = flnm
        else
            GetBytes = Mid(flnm, startPos, bytes)
        end if
'        Dim objFSO
'        Dim objFTemp
'        Dim objTextStream
'        Dim lngSize
'        
'        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'        
'        ' First, we get the filesize
'        Set objFTemp = objFSO.GetFile(flnm)
'        lngSize = objFTemp.Size
'        set objFTemp = nothing
'        
'        fsoForReading = 1
'        Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(flnm, fsoForReading)
'        
'        if offset > 0 then
'            strBuff = objTextStream.Read(offset - 1)
'        end if
'        
'        if bytes = -1 then        ' Get All!
'            GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(lngSize)  'ReadAll
'        else
'            GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(bytes)
'        end if
'        
'        objTextStream.Close
'        set objTextStream = nothing
'        set objFSO = nothing
    End Function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Functions to convert two bytes to a numeric value (long)   :::
    ':::  (both little-endian and big-endian)                        :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    Private Function lngConvert(strTemp)
        lngConvert = clng(asc(left(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(right(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
    end function

    Private Function lngConvert2(strTemp)
        lngConvert2 = clng(asc(right(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(left(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
    end function

    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  This function does most of the real work. It will attempt  :::
    ':::  to read any file, regardless of the extension, and will    :::
    ':::  identify if it is a graphical image.                       :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::  Passed:                                                    :::
    ':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::
    ':::       width       => width of image                         :::
    ':::       height      => height of image                        :::
    ':::       depth       => color depth (in number of colors)      :::
    ':::       strImageType=> type of image (e.g. GIF, BMP, etc.)    :::
    ':::                                                             :::
    ':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    function gfxSpex(flnm, width, height, depth, strImageType)
        dim strPNG 
        dim strGIF
        dim strBMP
        dim strType
        dim strBuff
        dim lngSize
        dim flgFound
        dim strTarget
        dim lngPos
        dim ExitLoop
        dim lngMarkerSize

        strType = ""
        strImageType = "(unknown)"

        gfxSpex = False

        strPNG = chr(137) & chr(80) & chr(78)
        strGIF = "GIF"
        strBMP = chr(66) & chr(77)

        strType = GetBytes(flnm, 0, 3)

        if strType = strGIF then                ' is GIF
            strImageType = "GIF"
            Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 7, 2))
            Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 9, 2))
            Depth = 2 ^ ((asc(GetBytes(flnm, 11, 1)) and 7) + 1)
            gfxSpex = True
        elseif left(strType, 2) = strBMP then        ' is BMP
            strImageType = "BMP"
            Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
            Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
            Depth = 2 ^ (asc(GetBytes(flnm, 29, 1)))
            gfxSpex = True
        elseif strType = strPNG then            ' Is PNG
            strImageType = "PNG"
            Width = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
            Height = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
            Depth = getBytes(flnm, 25, 2)
            select case asc(right(Depth,1))
                case 0
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 2
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 3)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 3
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))  '8
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 4
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 2)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case 6
                    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 4)
                    gfxSpex = True
                case else
                    Depth = -1
            end select
        else
            strBuff = GetBytes(flnm, 0, -1)        ' Get all bytes from file
            lngSize = len(strBuff)
            flgFound = 0

            strTarget = chr(255) & chr(216) & chr(255)
            flgFound = instr(strBuff, strTarget)

            if flgFound = 0 then
                exit function
            end if

            strImageType = "JPG"
            lngPos = flgFound + 2
            ExitLoop = false

            do while ExitLoop = False and lngPos < lngSize
                do while asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) = 255 and lngPos < lngSize
                    lngPos = lngPos + 1
                loop

                if asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) < 192 or asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) > 195 then
                    lngMarkerSize = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 1, 2))
                    lngPos = lngPos + lngMarkerSize  + 1
                else
                    ExitLoop = True
                end if
            loop

            if ExitLoop = False then
                Width = -1
                Height = -1
                Depth = -1
            else
                Height = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 4, 2))
                Width = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 6, 2))
                Depth = 2 ^ (asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 8, 1)) * 8)
                gfxSpex = True
            end if
        end if
    End Function
End Class
%>
```

Usage: create a new *.asp file with the following code to upload your files.

```
<!-- #include file="uploadhelper.asp" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<%=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>?cmd=upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      File: <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form> 
<%
If Request("cmd")="upload" Then
    Dim objUpload : Set objUpload = New UploadHelper
    If objUpload.GetError <> "" Then
        Response.Write("Warning: "&objUpload.GetError)
    Else  
        Response.Write("found "&objUpload.FileCount&" files...<br />")
        Dim x : For x = 0 To objUpload.FileCount - 1
            Response.Write("form field name: "&objUpload.File(x).FormFieldName&"<br />")
            Response.Write("content disposition: "&objUpload.File(x).ContentDisposition&"<br />")
            Response.Write("file name: "&objUpload.File(x).FileName&"<br />")
            Response.Write("file type: "&objUpload.File(x).ContentType&"<br />")
            Response.Write("file size: "&objUpload.File(x).Size&"<br />")
            Response.Write("image width: "&objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth&"<br />")
            Response.Write("image height: "&objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight&"<br />")
            If (objUpload.File(x).ImageWidth>1024) Or (objUpload.File(x).ImageHeight>1024) Then
                Response.Write("the image is too big, file not saved!")
            Else
                Call objUpload.File(x).SaveToDisk(Server.MapPath("/public"), "")
                Response.Write("file saved successfully!")
            End If
            Response.Write("<hr />")
        Next            
    End If
End If
%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a PPS, the problem might be a little more basic than you might think.  IIS has a limit of 200K for a BinaryRead() function call.  Has anyone come into this problem while trying to implement this solution?

Why wasn't the BinaryRead() limitation mentioned anywhere in the initial documentation?  I've been struggling with this for over an hour.

This link on StackOverflow explains it: [Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes) throws error for large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209227/request-binaryreadrequest-totalbytes-throws-error-for-large-files)

Comment: Valid point, thanks. This doesn't fit as answer though, but rather a comment. Edited my answer to reflect this and save people some future time.