# How to upload file and other information using Classic ASP

Tags: web-applications, asp-classic

What is the alternative for classic ASP like in php for uploading a file and other information from a form?

PHP would be

```
$mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
$file = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']
```

and then use insert SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO `Assignment_scripts` (`file` `name``module`)
VALUES ('{$file}', {$date}, '{$mcode}'
```

So how is this possible in Classic ASP .. do we use

```
request.file("uploaded_file")
```

to get the file information?

I did read some articles but they all say that it cannot be done in simple statements. It need a uploader.asp or other methods to retrieve the binary code....

Please enlighten me about this problem...

Many thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pure ASP upload with image detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection)

Comment: I need code to upload in the sql server.. is there an alternative beside using fileuploader.asp....

Comment: You want the file as a blog in the DB?

Comment: anything that can help me upload the file in database without any hustle ..

Comment: @Diodeus not really a dupe, my post is pretty much specific for images.  Of course it can be used for any files, but there are more simple scripts out there. :)