# how to get file name in classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

Problem:  I have a form

```
<form action="validate.asp" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
```

which has a file field input `type= "file"`

now I need to retrieve the file name in the validate.asp, here I cannot use `request.form(filename)` since it uses `multipart/form-data` .

What is the solution?

Re-edit:
this is my form

```
<form action="validate.asp" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"> 

<input name="ename" type="text" />
 <input name="file" type="file" /> 
<input name="Add" type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

now when the submit button is pressed i want the validate page to hold the name of the file ... for example dim fileName contains the name of the file just the name.... how to do this. this doesnot work Set fileName= Upload.Form("file") how to solve this problem.

Comment: improve your question give more details about how you are uploading your file ( wich component are you using), add some relevant code to get the context. and in specific the filename behave different in the each browser-engine (webkit, gecko, trident, blink) i suggest you to give a expanded context about if your app is in an enterprise app or just another internet app.

Comment: this is my form
 <form action="validate.asp" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
  
    <input name="ename" type="text" />
  <input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="Add" type="Submit"/>
</form>

now when the submit button is pressed i want the validate page to hold the name of the file ... 

for example dim fileName contains the name of the file just the name.... how to do this. 

this doesnot work
Set fileName= Upload.Form("file")

how to solve this problem..

Comment: put that on your question **edit** ...

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is by using upload script that will handle the raw data. Most upload scripts will give easy access to the form elements, so basic sample code would be:

```vbs
Dim objUpload, strFileName

'Initialize upload:
Set objUpload = New Uploader

'Get form element value:
strFileName = objUpload.Form("file")
```

You can find many free upload scripts by Googling and you can also use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15874740/447356) I posted here, originally meant for images but can also be used for ordinary upload.