# How to get SIze of image in Classic ASP using VB Script

Tags: asp-classic

I have a  in which i have uploaded a file, now i want to check before saving whether any file is uploaded or not. How can i check this.

I am using below code

```
    set objRQ = Server.CreateObject("DataFactory.Request")
if objRQ.Form("txtIcon").Size = 0 or objRQ.Form("txtImage").Size = 0 then
```

it doesn't worked then i changed code as following

```
if Request.Form("txtIcon").Count = 0 or Request.Form("txtImage").Count = 0 then
```

this is also not working.

Now Please provide your inputs to achieve this.

Comment: What is DataFactory.Request - some sort of upload component?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection)

Answer (score 1):

In Classic ASP you need a component to handle uploads or use a "pure ASP" upload solution like http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19297/Pure-ASP-File-Upload.htm. This will allow you to check if files were uploaded and the file size.

For example, using the class from the above codeguru page, you can iterate through the uploaded files like this:

```
<%
  Dim File
  For Each File In MyUploader.Files.Items
    Response.Write "File Name:" & File.FileName
    Response.Write "File Size:" & File.FileSize
    Response.Write "File Type:" & File.ContentType
  Next
%>
```

If you want to see the image size, as in the height and width of the image, then you will need to use either an image component or the LoadPicture method, eg:

```
<% 
Set img= LoadPicture(Server.MapPath(path))
width = img.width
height = img.width
%>
```