# xcode and ASP.net or ASP

Tags: ios, xcode, image, upload, asp-classic

I would like to upload an screenshot of an ipad to the server with specific name of file.

I have done the screenshot works perfect 
I have send it via E-Mail works also fine

But the problem is the ASP File

I read alot about Option Post in XCODE and send Image to server. But I never get any information about the *.ASP file.

How should this file look like? I'm not very familiar with ASP Programming :-)

Maybe someone can help me to generate the right *.ASP File for the POST Command to save the image on server!

Comment: If you're asking how to upload a file with Classic ASP you should look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190305/how-to-upload-files-with-asp-classic

Comment: Thanks  But That is not really what I need

Comment: I would like to use this asp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection how does the xcode look like

Comment: I have found maybe a solution with code from here