# ASP Classic parse data from curl POST -F

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have the following CURL request which pointing to my service:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://go.example.com/ \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: cf0c1ab5-08ff-1aa2-428e-24b855e1a61c' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F fff=vvvvv \
  -F rrrr=ddddd \
  -F xx=something
```

I'm trying to catch the xx paramter in classic ASP code.
I tried 'Request("xx")' and 'Request.Form("xx")'.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [CURL documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

> -F, --form
>
> (HTTP SMTP IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. **This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data** according to RFC 2388.

When a form is submitted to Classic ASP using a content-type of `multipart/form-data` the only method available is `Request.BinaryRead()` as `Request.Form` is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Here is a quick example of calling `Request.BinaryRead()` to get you started:

```
<%
'Should be less than configured request limit in IIS.
Const maxRequestSizeLimit = ...
Dim dataSize: dataSize = Request.TotalBytes
Dim formData

If dataSize < maxRequestSizeLimit Then
  'Read bytes into a SafeArray
  formData = Request.BinaryRead(dataSize)
  'Once you have a SafeArray its up to you to process it.
  ...
Else
  Response.Status = "413 PAYLOAD TOO LARGE"
  Response.End
End If
%>
```

---

#### Parsing a SafeArray isn't easy

If you want to still use `Request.Form` you can do by specifying the form parameters in the CURL command using `-d` instead of `-F`. From [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html);

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. **This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. Compare to -F, --form.

So the CURL command would be something like;

```
curl -X POST \
  http://go.mytest-service.com/ \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d fff=vvvvv \
  -d rrrr=ddddd \
  -d xx=something
```

You would then retrieve the `xx` parameter in Classic ASP using;

```
<%
Dim xx: xx = Request.Form("xx")
%>
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/692942)
- [MSDN - Request.BinaryRead Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525710(v=vs.90))
- [Example class for parsing a SafeArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874741/692942) *(specifically the `BuildUpload()` method which takes a SafeArray and parses the binary)*
- [Example implemenation of a File Uploader class using Request.BinaryRead() on Planet Source Code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7361&lngWId=4)

Comment: That Request.BinaryRead seems to get me somewhere...
I'll let you know how i'm doing.

10x!

Comment: @GilAllen word of warning, parsing a binary SafeArray is not for the faint hearted in Classic ASP. You could avoid this by using `-d` instead of `-F` to POST data using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `multipart/form-data` which will allow you to retrieve the values using `Request.Form`.

Comment: Indeed, but I'n not always the sending side.
Any way , it seems the sender side have changed the POST format and it works normally now.