# ActiveFile.Post Alternative for Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2016

Currently, we use ActiveFile.post in our ASP scripts to help deal with post requests that contain multipart/form-data. We're now upgrading our servers from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016 and we're finding that the install file we have to install ActiveFile doesn't run on Windows Server 2016

So I'm looking for either a replacement for ActiveFile in our scripts or some guidance on how to get the installer to install correctly

I've already attempted to contact support for Activefile but to all of my research the company that created it has since gone out of business

```
Set m_Post = Server.CreateObject("ActiveFile.Post")
m_Post.Upload UploadPath()

object.SetData "A", m_Post.FormInputs("A").value
object.SetData "B", Server.HtmlEncode(m_Post.FormInputs("B").Value)
object.SetData "C", m_Post.FormInputs("C").Value
```

When I try to run the installer I get no response of any kind. Nothing appears in task manager even when running the file as an administrator or from the administrator account

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: You can do your own method to do that.  It is little tricky, but with pure classic asp code, it will always run, no third party to install.

Comment: Alternatively, you can give Persits' ASPUpload a go. Very good experience with it.

Comment: If you're trying to upload a file you can do it with pure VBScript code - as @DanB says - without the need to install a third party component.  There are already questions on SO about this - eg this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection.  You'll probably want to find a ready made class file rather than write one from scratch yourself.  FreeAspUpload was a popular one.  The site where it could be found vanished a long time ago, but Web Archive is your friend -  http://web.archive.org/web/20130824234023/http://www.freeaspupload.net/